# Reference Request on logarithm derivative of L-functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory

I'm looking for references that show almost all Dirichlet characters $\chi \mod q$ satisfy
$$|\frac{L'}{L}(1+it, \chi)|=o(\log q)$$
where $t\in \mathbb{R}$ is fixed. I have been able to adapt a method of [Granville-Soundararajan](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0501232) to show results in this direction, but I wonder if there were published results on this problem: the method of theirs gives much stronger results than what I need. So I want to ask about the existence of earlier researches on this question.

I'm aware of papers by [Ihara-Murty-Shimura](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kenkyubu/emeritus/ihara/Publications-and-Recent-Preprints/RecentArticles/pdf-files/IMS.main.pdf) and perhaps another one by Ihara and Matsumoto that assumed GRH, [the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Riemann_hypothesis) However, in this case the question is made too easy since

$$|\frac{L'}{L}(1+it)| \ll \log\log q,$$
as is mentioned in textbooks.

Comment: Why do you attempt to perform an edit with a different username, given that you are a registered user of MO?

Comment: @AlexM. I just tried to update some information I know for this question, so that others can help me better. I don't know what do you mean by names, and I don't think I changed that after asking.

Comment: You tried to perform that edit while connected with [a different username](https://mathoverflow.net/users/129127/j-pan), which doesn't make sense. Please use a single account on this site. This will also allow you to edit your question as it pleases you. (The previous attempt was rejected precisely because it was done under a different username.)

Comment: @AlexM. Yes you are right, and thanks for pointing that. By the way, do you have the edition that you rejected? I want to cite a hyperlink but can't find it now.

Comment: The whole history of this post can be found at https://mathoverflow.net/posts/306832/timeline. In particular, that rejected edit attempt can be found at https://mathoverflow.net/review/suggested-edits/104626.